# How to query datatable from a datadictionary for a given id

Tags: c#, data-dictionary

Hi

I have problem in reading a data table which has given id in the dictionary. Any one help me please. Below is my code. I have a dictionary datasourceData I am storing data table. I need to retrieve the datatable stored in the dictionary for the given id.

```
public Dictionary<Guid, DataTable> dataSourceData { get; set; }

public DataModel()
        {
            dataSourceData = new Dictionary<Guid, DataTable>();
            logger = new BasicFileLogger.Logger();
        }

public DataTable GetDataSourceDescriptionById(Guid piId)
        {
            if (piId == null || piId == Guid.Empty)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("No such datasourcedescriptionId");
            try
            {
                return dataSourceData.Values.Where(db => db.Equals(piId));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.WriteException(ex);
                throw new InvalidOperationException(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple access it using the key:

```
if(dataSourceData.ContainsKey(yourGUID))
    DataTable dt = dataSourceData[yourGUID];
```

where `yourGUID` is the `GUID` you want to access against, you may check if your dictionary contains the `GUID` key, so you method could be:

```
public DataTable GetDataSourceDescriptionById(Guid piId)
        {
            Dictionary<Guid, DataTable> dataSourceData = new Dictionary<Guid, DataTable>();
            if (dataSourceData.ContainsKey(piId))
            {
                return dataSourceData[piId];
            }
            else
            {
                InvalidOperationException ex = new InvalidOperationException("No such datasourcedescriptionId"));
                logger.WriteException(ex);
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

you want to change this line

```
return dataSourceData.Values.Where(db => db.Equals(piId));
```

to

```
return dataSourceData[piId];
```

Comment: Briliant, feel free to mark the question as answered. you can do that by selecting the tick to the left for any one of your answerers

Comment: how to select all correct answer, if i select yours it unchecking the rest :-)

Comment: Nah you can only check one. Your favourite one.